# How to get your Facebook likes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

If you start a new Facebook app and use the Heroku server, they start you off with a sample application that displays a few of your likes.

It does this using PHP. How do you do the same thing using JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching current user likes in Facebook](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6001866/fetching-current-user-likes-in-facebook)

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the `user_likes` permission from the user, it's just a call to
`FB.api('/me/likes');`

(using Facebook's Javascript SDK)

Comment: Do you have the user_likes permission? (a call to /me/permissions' will confirm what permissions you have)

Comment: Yeah, it was already there in the sample program. Assuming that I have the necessary permissions, can you show the Javascript to store the likes in a variable or display them?